# django-compressor error after updating JS libraries to use npm

Tags: javascript, amazon-s3, django-compressor

I had a set of JS static files being uploaded to S3 and compressed with django-compressor. django-compressor didn't give any issues during a deploy before. After I switched from JS files from living in codebase and started using npm to install the various JS libraries, django-compressor is giving me errors:

Here is the list of scripts in base template before using npm:

```
{# Can't compress this guy #}
    <script src="{{STATIC_URL}}shared/ckeditor/ckeditor.js"></script>
  {% block scripts %}{% compress js %}
    <script src="{{STATIC_URL}}shared/stacktrace-js/dist/stacktrace.js"></script>
    <script src="{{STATIC_URL}}shared/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="{{STATIC_URL}}shared/jquery-growl/1.2.3/jquery.growl.js"></script>
    <script src="{{STATIC_URL}}shared/jquery-ui-1.12.1.custom/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
    <script src="{{STATIC_URL}}ckeditor/ckeditor-init.js"></script>
    <script src="{{STATIC_URL}}shared/ckeditor-custom/ckeditor-custom.js"></script>
    <script src="{{STATIC_URL}}shared/bootstrap/3.3.5/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <script src="{{STATIC_URL}}shared/utils.js"></script>
    <script src="{{STATIC_URL}}shared/angular/1.3.11/angular.min.js"></script>
    <script src="{{STATIC_URL}}shared/angular/1.3.11/angular-route.min.js"></script>
    <script src="{{STATIC_URL}}shared/angular/1.3.11/angular-cookies.min.js"></script>
    <script src="{{STATIC_URL}}shared/angular-bootstrap/0.11.0/ui-bootstrap-tpls-0.11.0.min.js"></script>
    <script src="{{STATIC_URL}}shared/bootstrap-multiselect/bootstrap-multiselect.js"></script>
    <script src="{{STATIC_URL}}shared/introjs/intro.js"></script>
    <script type="text/django" src="{{STATIC_URL}}shared/ch-error-logging.js"></script>
    <script type="text/django" src="{{STATIC_URL}}shared/ch-config.js"></script>
    <script src="{{STATIC_URL}}shared/angulartics/dist/angulartics.min.js"></script>
    <script src="{{STATIC_URL}}shared/angulartics-segment/dist/angulartics-segment.min.js"></script>
    <script src="{{STATIC_URL}}shared/chart.js/dist/Chart.min.js"></script>
    <script src="{{STATIC_URL}}shared/select2/dist/js/select2.min.js"></script>
    <script src="{{STATIC_URL}}shared/angular-chart.js/dist/angular-chart.js"></script>
    <script src="{{STATIC_URL}}shared/jquery-validation/dist/jquery.validate.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/django" src="{{STATIC_URL}}shared/ch-track.js"></script>
    <script type="text/django" src="{{STATIC_URL}}shared/ch-file.js"></script>
    <script src="{{STATIC_URL}}shared/offline.js"></script>
    {% endcompress %}
```

And here they are after using NPM:

```
{# Can't compress this guy #}
    <script src="{{STATIC_URL}}shared/ckeditor/ckeditor.js"></script>
  {% block scripts %}{% compress js %}
    <script src="{{STATIC_URL}}shared/stacktrace-js/dist/stacktrace.js"></script>
    <script src="{{STATIC_URL}}shared/jquery/dist/jquery.js"></script>
    <script src="{{STATIC_URL}}shared/jquery-growl/1.2.3/jquery.growl.js"></script>
    <script src="{{STATIC_URL}}shared/jquery-ui-dist/jquery-ui.js"></script>
    <script src="{{STATIC_URL}}ckeditor/ckeditor-init.js"></script>
    <script src="{{STATIC_URL}}shared/ckeditor-custom/ckeditor-custom.js"></script>
    <script src="{{STATIC_URL}}shared/bootstrap/3.3.5/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <script src="{{STATIC_URL}}shared/utils.js"></script>
    <script src="{{STATIC_URL}}shared/angular/angular.js"></script>
    <script src="{{STATIC_URL}}shared/angular-route/angular-route.min.js"></script>
    <script src="{{STATIC_URL}}shared/angular-cookies/angular-cookies.min.js"></script>
    <script src="{{STATIC_URL}}shared/angular-bootstrap/0.11.0/ui-bootstrap-tpls-0.11.0.min.js"></script>
    <script src="{{STATIC_URL}}shared/bootstrap-multiselect/bootstrap-multiselect.js"></script>
    <script src="{{STATIC_URL}}shared/introjs/intro.js"></script>
    <script type="text/django" src="{{STATIC_URL}}shared/ch-error-logging.js"></script>
    <script type="text/django" src="{{STATIC_URL}}shared/ch-config.js"></script>
    <script src="{{STATIC_URL}}shared/angulartics/src/angulartics.js"></script>
    <script src="{{STATIC_URL}}shared/angulartics-segment/lib/angulartics-segment.js"></script>
    <script src="{{STATIC_URL}}shared/chart.js/dist/Chart.min.js"></script>
    <script src="{{STATIC_URL}}shared/select2/dist/js/select2.js"></script>
    <script src="{{STATIC_URL}}shared/angular-chart.js/dist/angular-chart.js"></script>
    <script src="{{STATIC_URL}}shared/jquery-validation/dist/jquery.validate.js"></script>
    <script type="text/django" src="{{STATIC_URL}}shared/ch-track.js"></script>
    <script type="text/django" src="{{STATIC_URL}}shared/ch-file.js"></script>
    <script src="{{STATIC_URL}}shared/offline.js"></script>
    {% endcompress %}
```

The error I get during deployment while it is compressing is the following:

> Compressing... CommandError: An error occurred during rendering
>   /opt/codedeploy-agent/deployment-root/b2386cb6-3ef9-459c-b994-814b98b73cbc/d-WGY3CJ5BN/deployment-archive/chalktalk/pages/templates/pages/terms.html:
>   /opt/codedeploy-agent/deployment-root/b2386cb6-3ef9-459c-b994-814b98b73cbc/d-WGY3CJ5BN/deployment-archive/node_modules/yuglify/bin/yuglify:77
>                   throw(err);
>
> ^ SyntaxError: Unexpected token: punc (;)
>       at JS_Parse_Error.Object.defineProperty.get (eval at  (/opt/codedeploy-agent/deployment-root/b2386cb6-3ef9-459c-b994-814b98b73cbc/d-WGY3CJ5BN/deployment-archive/node_modules/uglify-js/tools/node.js:27:1),
>   :86:23)

Comment: as i suggested in your previous question, you could comment out chunks of the libraries binary-search-style and find out which ones are causing the problem.

Comment: That will break the code due to a lot of references to the libraries. It's a lot of work to do and don't see it being effective?

Comment: of course it breaks the code, but right now it doesn't work at all and you want to find out where that syntax error comes from. breaking stuff is sometimes part of debugging isn't it? to elaborate on the binary search method, you can comment out half of the libraries, check whether it works. if it doesn't, you continue with the current half of the libraries, halving that again, if it does work, then you continue with the commented out half of the libraries. that's five steps in total, not a lot of work, and you wouldn't need to wait days for an SO answer :)